# Problem with decimal field in django v3.2

Tags: django, django-3.2

After upgrading from version 3.1 to version 3.2, I found precision problem in using decimal field. Following example is a small code which could regenerate problem.

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        null=False,
        decimal_places=18,
        max_digits=44)


# A simple insertion example 
from api.models import Foo
from django.db.models import F
from decimal import Decimal

f = Foo.objects.create(amount=Decimal('0.5'))
f.amount = F('amount') - Decimal('0.4')
f.save(update_fields=['amount', ])
f.refresh_from_db()
print(f.amount)
```

This code generates `0.099999999999999980` but same code in previous version generate expected result `0.01`. By checking mysql query generated for update query, I found that in new version number has sent using a quotation but in previous one there were no quotation. i.e in new version we have something like this `` UPDATE `api_foo` SET `amount` = (`api_foo`.`amount` - '0.4') WHERE `api_foo`.`id` = 1 `` but in previous one we had `` UPDATE `api_foo` SET `amount` = (`api_foo`.`amount` - 0.4) WHERE `api_foo`.`id` = 1 ``. Also I must mention that this happens just in mysql driver not in sqllite.

I know this seems like a bug, but I guessed that I am missing something trivial.

I am using mysql-8.0.19 and I got the same value in versions 3.2 and 3.2.3 of django.

Comment: Did you try to set the decimal precision? getcontext().prec = 18

Comment: I tried this too, and get the same result. Notice that it generates correct results in previous version.